# Laravel 5.7: Custom blade template for Maintenance Mode but not 503.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Every time `php artisan down` is turned on, Laravel displays 503 page.

OK. I can customise it by creating new file called `503.blade.php` inside `resources/views/errors`.

The point is that I don't consider Maintenance Mode as error at any point despite of the fact that it makes website unavailable for a client.

> The 503 Service Unavailable error is a server-side error, meaning the
> problem is usually with the website's server. ... Even though the 503
> Service Unavailable error means that there's an error on another
> computer, the issue is probably only temporary.

**How can I define my own blade template (let's say `maintenance_mode.blade.php`) to customize what users see during the app down and leave 503 intact?**

My efforts: I investigated the middleware itself inside the vendor but it only throws the exception, I assume the exception is being caught somewhere with and handles response with a corresponding view? Can someone point me on how to achieve what I need?

Thanks

Comment: i have edited the answer check it now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way could be to change render method in Exception's Handler. Something like:

```
// app_path('Exceptions/Handler.php');

/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Exceptions\MaintenanceModeException) {
        return response()
            ->view('maintenance.down', [
                'message' => 'Come back later.'
            ], 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    }

    // in Laravel 8.x MaintenanceModeException is deprecated and one should rely on 
    // @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
    // or
    // \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\ServiceUnavailableHttpException
    if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException ) {
        return response()
            ->view('maintenance.down', [
                'message' => 'Come back later.'
            ], 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Thanks to @Ifnot 's input, answer is updated to comply Laravel 8.x

Comment: Apparently modifying `render` inside `Handler.php` was the easiest solution. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Be careful, `MaintenanceModeException` is now deprecated and may break anytime in future versions of laravel. I wonder if we can just check for `$exception->getStatusCode() == 503` for detecting the good HttpException now.

Answer (score 3):

If You want to display custom message in server maintanence(503.blade.php)

Laravel Has the out of box customization

```
php artisan down --message="We are Upgrading look and feel"
```

now We `are Upgrading look and feel` will be displayed in page while user visiting the page

If You want More customization kindly Look up the package

```
https://github.com/MisterPhilip/maintenance-mode
```

If this answer is `irrelevnt` or not `fixed your problem` kindly comment below so that i can fix that

Hope it helps

Edited

Ok then run the command in your terminal

`php artisan vendor:publish` and choose `0` so that it will publish all the views and configs

now open your view folder there will be a `errors`

folder and you can see the `list of error files` provided by `laravel`  now change as per  your customization and run php artisan `opt:clear` it will clear all the `cache views ,configs`  and now try it

by Customising your `503.blade.php` its works fine form me now

you can just view the tutorial of customising `404.blade.php` and customize as per the requirement

[Customize 404 in laravel](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-create-custom-404-error-page-in-laravel-57example.html)

Comment: Yes, it's irrelevant. I want a custom blade template rather than custom message. I know I can change it thanks to the docs. Also I see no point of using 3rd party package just to use different template. I keep my software clean and minimal. Thanks for your efforts anyway.

Comment: Tried with laravel 8, `down --message` is not usable anymore.

Comment: It's because in laravel 8 . Maintenance mode is changed entirely